# How to transform a xml into a html with the xml tags and attributes as text of a html with equivalent tree, using XSLT?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I think I never asked a question with such an incomprehensible title, sorry about that.

Let say the XML file I have look like that (not that I don't want to copy/paste, but it's too big):

```
<A attr1="aaa" attr2="bbb">
    <B attr8="23156">
        <C attr10="bla"/>
        <C attr10="bli"/>
        <C attr10="blo"/>
    </B>
</A>
<A attr1="jhg" attr2="ygyug">
    <B attr8="126">
        <C attr10="bla"/>
    </B>
    <B attr8="102">
        <C attr10="bla"/>
        <C attr10="blo"/>
    </B>
</A>
```

Well, you got the point, a generic XML file. I don't know the tags, the tags order, and the attributes.
I have to use XSLT to turn this XML into a HTML file with all the "nodes" and attributes of the xml as text, in an equivalent tree :

```
<div>
    &lt;A attr1="aaa" attr2="bbb"&gt;
    <div>
        &lt;B attr8="23156"&gt;
        <div>&lt;C attr10="bla"/&gt;</div>
        <div>&lt;C attr10="bli"/&gt;</div>
        <div>&lt;C attr10="blo"/&gt;</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    &lt;A attr1="jhg" attr2="ygyug"&gt;
    <div>
        &lt;B attr8="126"&gt;
        <div>&lt;C attr10="bla"/&gt;</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        &lt;B attr8="102"&gt;
        <div>&lt;C attr10="bla"/&gt;</div>
        <div>&lt;C attr10="blo"/&gt;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can get every nodes' name by selecting //node(), I can get attributes by selecting @*, but I can't figure out how to get the html as expected.

Any help you can give will be greatly appreciated :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying the following XSLT to your sample should produce the expected result with a (minor) difference in space before the slash caracter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <div>
     &lt;<xsl:value-of select="name()"/><xsl:value-of select="' '"/><xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/><xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="close-if-leaf"/>&gt;
     <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="close-if-leaf">
    <xsl:if test="count(*) = 0">/</xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>=&quot;<xsl:value-of select="."/>&quot;<xsl:value-of select="' '"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Nice, it's exactly what I need, thanks you ! I disovered "close-if-leaf" mode today :)